# What is the 4pin connector next to this USB on the Creality 4.2.3 board?

Tags: creality

[image]

What is the 4pin connector next to this USB on the Creality 4.2.3 board?

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Can you add a photo that shows the silk screen next to the 4-pin header, so turn the board 180° clockwise. This is most probably a header for the USB. So you can either use the micro USB or the 4-pin header.

Comment: @0scar: Oh, that would be really nice! (for wiring direct to the rpi in an electronics enclosure without awkward USB cables). Is this something other boards have too?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Yes, some boards do, I think I have 1 or 2 boards with that option, but, I don't own a v4.2.3 board (which is hard to find info on... hence the request for a photo from the other side).